# Why would a provided prolog function not be allowed to be used twice in the program

Tags: prolog

error: Full stop in clause-body?  Cannot redefine ,/2

I understand that the error is caused when our Prolog system already provides X/2, and you cannot redefine it. so you can either omit your own definition (thus, using the system-provided one instead) or rename your predicate - but im not understanding why I would be getting the error with this code

```
county_deaths(onedia,45).
county_deaths(essex,0).
county_deaths(franklin,0).
county_deaths(clinton,4).
county_deaths(fulton,19).
county_deaths(hamilton,1).
county_deaths(herkimer,3).
county_deaths(saratoga,14).
county_deaths(stLawrence,2).
county_deaths(warren,27).
county_deaths(washington,14).
county_deaths(lewis,5).

county_cases(clinton,95).
county_cases(essex, 36).
county_cases(franklin, 20).
county_cases(fulton, 196).
county_cases(hamilton, 5).
county_cases(herkimer, 103).
county_cases(lewis, 20).
county_cases(onedia, 917).
county_cases(saratoga, 463).
county_cases(stLawrence, 197).
county_cases(warren, 251).
county_cases(washington, 228).


start :-
  findall( N , county_deaths(_,N), [N|Ns] ) ,
  min_max( Ns , N , N , Min, Max ) ,
  display_max(Max),
  display_min(Min)
  .
  findall( N , county_cases(_,N), [N|Ns] ) ,
  min_max( Ns , N , N , Min, Max ) ,
  display_maxCase(Max),
  display_minCase(Min)
  .

min_max( []     , Min , Max , Min , Max ) .
min_max( [N|Ns] , X   , Y   , Min , Max ) :- N < X , !, min_max(Ns,N,Y,Min,Max) .
min_max( [N|Ns] , X   , Y   , Min , Max ) :- N > Y , !, min_max(Ns,X,N,Min,Max) .
min_max( [_|Ns] , X   , Y   , Min , Max ) :-            min_max(Ns,X,Y,Min,Max) .

% multiple counties could have the same number of deaths, so
% we use findall/3 to enumerate all counties with the specified
% number of deaths.

display_max(N) :-
  findall(C,county_deaths(C,N),Cs) ,
  writeln(max_deaths:Cs:N)
  .

display_min(N) :-
  findall(C,county_deaths(C,N),Cs) ,
  writeln(min_deaths:Cs:N)
  .
display_maxCase(N) :-
  findall(C,county_cases(C,N),Cs) ,
  writeln(max_cases:Cs:N)
  .

display_minCase(N) :-
  findall(C,county_cases(C,N),Cs) ,
  writeln(min_cases:Cs:N)
  .
```

I believe the error is with the findall function - but that is something prolog provides and i need to use this method 3 times in my program. I have tried to solve this by renaming the method - but then it is no longer the provided findall function. how can i get around this error?

Comment: Your `start` has a full-stop on a line by itself... and then keeps going into `findall` - so the full-stop should be a comma.

Comment: after i corrected this by putting a comma, the rest of the code still doesnt work/display @brebs